# mktime() returns an incorrect value right after entering DST

Tags: dst, busybox, mktime, real-time-clock, hwclock

The following snippet code is from `rtc.c` in `busybox-1.22.1`.

In my case the `utc` is always 0, so this function is just doing a conversion from `struct tm` to `time_t`.

```
time_t FAST_FUNC rtc_tm2time(struct tm *ptm, int utc)
{
    //fprintf(stdout, "ptm->tm_hour: %d\n", ptm->tm_hour);
    char *oldtz = oldtz; /* for compiler */
    time_t t;

    if (utc) {
        oldtz = getenv("TZ");
        putenv((char*)"TZ=UTC0");
        tzset();
    }

    t = mktime(ptm); //problem here
    //struct tm* temp = localtime(&t);
    //fprintf(stdout, "temp->tm_hour: %d\n", temp->tm_hour);

    if (utc) {
        unsetenv("TZ");
        if (oldtz)
        {
            putenv(oldtz - 3);
        }
        tzset();
    }

    return t;
}
```

Also, there is a file `/etc/TZ` displaying timezone and DST information.

```
~ # cat /etc/TZ
LMT0:00LMT-1:00,M8.5.1/10,M12.5.1/10
```

Then, I set system time to 2021/8/30, 9:59:30 (30 seconds earlier than DST start date), and sync to hwclock.

```
date -s 2021.08.30-09:59:30 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null //set system time
hwclock -w //sync RTC to system time
```

Entering hwclock continuously while observing the output on CLI.

```
~ # hwclock
ptm->tm_hour : 9
temp->tm_hour : 9
Mon Aug 30 09:59:58 2021  0.000000 seconds

~ # hwclock
ptm->tm_hour : 10
temp->tm_hour : 11 //why not 10?
Mon Aug 30 11:00:00 2021  0.000000 seconds
```

Why the return value from `mktime` is added by 1 when entering DST? Shouldn't it be affected by DST?

Answer (score 1):

According to the `mktime()` [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime), `mktime()` is allowed to update the `tm_isdst` value.  The starting value may cause the `mktime()` algorithm to branch differently:

```
The value specified in the tm_isdst field informs mktime() whether or not 
daylight saving time (DST) is in effect for the time supplied in the tm 
structure: a positive value means DST is in effect; zero means that DST is not in 
effect; and a negative value means that mktime() should (use timezone information 
and system databases to) attempt to determine whether DST is in effect at the 
specified time.
```

and then update the value of `tm_isdst` accordingly:

```
tm_isdst is set (regardless of its initial value) to a positive value or to 0, 
respectively, to indicate whether DST is or is not in effect at the specified time.
```

In other words, I'd check the `tm_isdst` value before and after the `mktime()` call.

One way I've dealt with this in the past is to

- call `mktime()` with a known value of `tm_isdst` (e.g. zero or one)
- call `localtime()` on the returned time_t value, then check `tm_isdst` on the struct tm pointer `localtime()` returns.
- if the `tm_isdst` has been changed from the prior known value, change the original struct tm to use the new `tm_isdt` value then call `mktime()` again with it before trusting the time_t it returns.

It's definitely less efficient but it's possible to know when the DST change occurs by expecting it and checking for it.

Another option would be to set `tm_isdst` to -1 before calling `mktime()` and trusting its lookup of timezone and set `tm_isdst` appropriately.